# Best practice arguments in VueJS, am I wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

We've written a custom table that's based on tb-table.
we've also written a custom search component.
its bound to a search filter and runs a function per keypress called searchBarEvents @input.

```
  <Searchbar
                        :dbSearch="config_t.dbSearch"
                        :debounce="computedItems.length>100"
                        :fields="searchColumns_t"
                        :table_length='computedItems.length'
                        @input="searchBarEvents"
                        input_placeholder="Search..."
                        v-if="config_t.search"
                        v-model="searchFilter"
                ></Searchbar>
```

Now this search filter is also taken into a computed property to enable a database search directly instead of just filtering.

```
computedSearchFilter() {
                let search = this.searchFilter;
                if (this.config_t.dbSearch && this.chosenColumn !== '') {
                    search = '';

                }
                return search;
            }
```

chosenColumn is the column you chose to search for in the table instead of filtering all the data.

```
searchBarEvents(eventObject, key) {
                let search = '';
                if (eventObject) {
                    search = eventObject;
                }
                if (key === 'undefined') {
                    this.chosenColumn = '';
                }
                if (key) {
                    this.chosenColumn = key.toLowerCase();
                }
                if (this.config_t.dbSearch) {
                    this.$emit('dbSearch', search, this.chosenColumn);
                }
            },
```

this is the way you emit the search value instead of just filtering if you've enabled database search.

and this is the computed property for the items in the table.

```
computedItems() {
                let specific = false;
                let valid;
                if (this.chosenColumn !== '' && !this.config_t.dbSearch) {
                    this.config_t.status.forEach((el, index) => {
                        if (el.key === this.chosenColumn) {
                            specific = true;
                            if (el.options[index + 1].name.toLowerCase().includes(this.computedSearchFilter.toLowerCase())) {
                                valid = Object.keys(el.options)[0];
                            }
                            if (el.options[index + 2].name.toLowerCase().includes(this.computedSearchFilter.toLowerCase())) {
                                valid === Object.keys(el.options)[0] ? valid = Object.keys(el.options)[0] : valid = Object.keys(el.options)[1];
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (specific && !_.isEmpty(this.computedSearchFilter)) {
                        return this.items_t.filter(item => {
                            return item[this.chosenColumn].toString().toLowerCase().includes(valid)
                        });
                    } else {
                        return this.items_t.filter(item => {
                            return item[this.chosenColumn].toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.computedSearchFilter.toLowerCase())
                        });
                    }
                }
                return this.items_t.filter(item => {
                    return Object.values(item).toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.computedSearchFilter.toLowerCase())
                });
            },
},
```

I know its long.

thing is, my senior keeps telling me, my code is bad and over convoluted.
I keep stressing that in order for me to enable lots of functionally I need to make lots of small adjustments and that this code can't be over simplified just because its best practice.
its a hard to understand code, I agree.
But in order to allow: searching per column, searching in all the columns, db search in all the columns and db search in specific columns without proc-ing the normal search filter - the algorithem is going to be long and tiring.

we've gotten into a small argument.
and he claims that my ego prevents me from seeing this is not how code is supposed to be written and that I should refactor it completely.
And I keep telling him that, its not bad, its complicated, as some code can be.

Question is, am I at the wrong here? is my code badly written and over complicated.
out of the best practice norm?

Comment: So you're sending up the column and sort direction, paging number and any search filtering to the server for it to run the query to return only the results needed? So why are you then filtering it in computedItems, I think that's what your colleague is on about.

Comment: the computed items is there because some columns can be filtered regularly in some columns and directly from the database in some columns, the table is used in various situations on various screens